# ServerName/ServerAlias in virtual host configuration

Tags: dns, centos, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have a VPS on which I am running Apache 2 (CentOS v5). I have my DNS setup as follows ...

```
(A Record) exampledomain.com points to 123.456.789.123
(CName Record) www.exampledomain.com points to exampledomain.com.
```

My question is what `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` values do I use in my Virtual Hosts configuration file so that visitors will be directed to my website whether they use `www.exampledomain.com` or `exampledomain.com`. Ideally I would like the hostname of the server to be reported as `www.exampledomain.com`.

I have this currently but I find it directs the user to the Apache default page. I am trying to follow the directions at [the Apache Documentation site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) but I must be messing something up.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@exampledomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exampledomain.com
    ServerName exampledomain.com
    ServerAlias *.exampledomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/exampledomain.com-error-log
    CustomLog /var/log/exampledomain.com-access-log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any example of what I am trying to acheive would be Google. Regardless of if I type `google.com` or `www.google.com` the URL changes to `www.google.com`.

Comment: Do you have actual content on the file system at /var/www/exampledomain.com?

Comment: Yes there is a working WordPress site there.

Comment: Where did you put that config? Is it within a file inside `sites-enabled`?

Comment: It is located in `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/vhosts.conf`. I have included this file in the `httpd.conf`

Comment: What do your `Include` lines look like?  What does the log show?  Have you restarted apache?

Comment: Are you saying that the config looks correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a RewriteCond and a RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^(www|s.\.www|m)\.nimblex\.(net) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.nimblex.net/$1 [L,R]
```